# I'm struggling with methods...particularly the arguments that you pass it.

Tags: java

I'm trying to teach myself Java and I'm having a hell of a time! :)
I just started the other day and I've hit a bit of a road block.

I'm trying to learn arrays, but my methods are also kinda jacked up.

I know when I invoke my method in my main that it isn't right. I thought I was supposed to give the method that I was invoking the arguments that it needs to carry out its processes?

I'm just trying to call my last method and display the data from that method.

```
package test_arraymethods;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TEST_arraymethods 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Please enter the total number of dealers: ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    int numDealers = input.nextInt();
    numDealers = numberOfDealers(numDealers);

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("Please enter the required data for each of your dealers: %n");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    dataCalculation(numDealers);

    //displayTotals(numberOfDealers, dealerNames, dealerSales, commissionRate);
}//main

//METHOD 1
public static int numberOfDealers(int dealers)
{
    int results;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(dealers < 0 || dealers > 30)
    {
        System.out.printf("%nEnter a valid number of dealers: %n");
        dealers = input.nextInt();  
    }
    results = dealers;
    return results;
}//number of dealers methods

//METHOD 2
public static void dataCalculation(int data)
{
    String[] dealerNames = new String[data];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("%nEnter the names of the dealers:%n ");

        for(int i = 0; i < data; i++)
        {
            String names =input.nextLine();
            dealerNames[i]= names;
        }

    double[] dealerSales = new double[data];
    System.out.printf("%nEnter their sales totals: %n");

        for(int i = 0; i < data; i++)
        {
            double sales = input.nextDouble();
            dealerSales[i] = sales;
        }
}//data calculations

//METHOD 3
public static double[] commission(double[] dealerSales)
{
    //Create array
    double[] commissionRate = new double[dealerSales.length]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < dealerSales.length; i++)
    {
            commissionRate[i] = dealerSales[i];

        if(commissionRate[i] > 0 && commissionRate[i] < 5000)
           commissionRate[i] = commissionRate[i] * 0.08; 
        else if(commissionRate[i] > 5000 && commissionRate[i] < 15000)
            commissionRate[i] = commissionRate[i] * 0.15;
        else if(commissionRate[i] > 15000)
            commissionRate[i] =  commissionRate[i] * 0.20;
    }
    return commissionRate;
}//commission method 

public static double[] dealershipSales(double[] dealerSales)
{
    //Create array
    double[] dealershipSalesTotal = new double[dealerSales.length]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < dealerSales.length; i++)
    {
        dealershipSalesTotal[i] += dealerSales[i];

    }
    return dealershipSalesTotal;
}//dealership sales

public static double[] dealerSalesAvg(double[] dealerSales)
{
    double[] dealerSalesAvgTotal = new double[dealerSales.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < dealerSales.length; i++)
    {
        dealerSalesAvgTotal[i] += dealerSales[i] / dealerSales.length;
    }

    return dealerSalesAvgTotal;
}//dealership sales averages

public static double[] dealershipTotalCommission(double[] commissionRate)
{
    double[] totalCommission = new double[commissionRate.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < commissionRate.length; i++)
    {
            totalCommission[i] += commissionRate[i];
    }
    return totalCommission;
}//total commission for the dealership

public static void displayTotals(double[] numberOfDealers, double[] dealerNames, double[] dealerSales, double[] commissionRate)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDealers.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(" " + dealerNames[i]);
        System.out.println(" " + dealerSales[i]);
        System.out.println(" " + commissionRate[i]);
    }


    // pass all of your values to this method and then display them
    //display the dealer name and amount of sales 
    //and the amount of commission for all dealers in a tabular format.

}//display totals */

}//class
```

Comment: The last comment in my main is what I was going to use to call my display method...

Comment: Please explain more clearly what your problem is; "it isn't right" doesn't give us much to work on.

Comment: before coding try to grasp the basic concept of programming. Also you do not have any Idea what programming is all about. Try to get hold of a teacher or follow some tutorials.

Comment: The problem is that it keeps giving me warnings regarding my actual parameters when I invoke the method in the main.

Thanks for the stellar advice Blip...smh

Comment: Your dataCalculation method effectively does nothing because it does a bunch of calculation and returns nothing. All of the variables it uses are from the local scope of the method.

Comment: Conscells, I will put a return on that method...I was going to call it from the main and have it return my data there! Thanks, for pointing that out. I kinda changed my plan for this project a couple times and I didn't update that...so I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can't get this to work:

```
    displayTotals(numberOfDealers, dealerNames, dealerSales, commissionRate);
```

is that it is referring to variables that are not in scope.  Those variables are all local variables within methods whose calls have finished.  If you want the variables to be accessible in another method, they must be declared as (static, in this case) fields.

Comment: OK, I appreciate it Stephen! I'm still a little confused...forgive me, I have only been messing with this language for a couple nights. 
So to declare them as static, I would just create a new variable and set it equal to the method that I need and then use that variable as my actual parameter?

Comment: Sort of.  What you actually need to do is to **move** the existing declarations to the class scope.  But surely your tutorial / book has explained the concept of a field to you .....